# OpenBSD 6.9 - ENOMEM error on execve (execvp)

Tags: openbsd, virtual-memory, exec, limit

I've compiled a program on OpenBSD 6.9 and when I execute the program, I get an enomem error related specifically to execvp which the man pages say is a font-end for execve.

The execve man page mentions that enomem is related to the process asking for more virtual memory than is allowed by the maximum.

My question specifically is, how does OpenBSD define virtual memory limits and how can I raise them? I've tried looking though login.conf which mentions I can raise the limit on vmemory but any attempt I've made to raise my limits past ~1 GB does not apply.

My second question would be, am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there something in the source code that needs to be tweaked to run on OpenBSD? The program is designed for AIX, Linux, macOS and Windows. BSD was not a consideration though I've read that AIX and macOS are similar to BSD

Thank you

Comment: What are your process limits? `ulimit -a`

Comment: Adding to Kusalananda's comment, how much memory and swap space does your machine have? Also, remember that after editing `login.conf` you have to run `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf` (`man 5 login.conf`) _and_ log out and back on (or start using a new login shell).

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thank you for the help, Kusalananda and Zé Loff.

I had read that manual for login.conf and the way it is written makes it sound like the cap_mkdb is optional based on how large the system is. I have a small personal system so I did not think it was necessary.